# Upload Multiple images to Laravel 5.8 Select, and specific remove before send to server

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a problem that I can't get a specific remove or delete from input file upload.
I implemented with default html multiple image upload, unfortunately if I want to remove any images from upload collection of array list by specifics remove, According to UI It's seem working well because I've rendered all the images from array to display with button remove as well.

***Problem:*** User removed by clicking on btn "Remove" then image has been disappeared, When I check the post from form with default debug of laravel called **dd() method** from : `action="{{ route('module.product.store') }}"` I'v seem that all images in array still appear.

***For example: ***
I uploaded with 3 images and then I removed 2 images from array uploaded, In UI is display only 1 Images and 2 Images has gone. I expected that image just only 1 upload to the server but when retrieve data from form POST sting get 3items in array.

HTML:Blade

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('module.product.store') }}" autocomplete="on" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="card-body">
        @csrf
        {{method_field('PUT')}}
        @include('partials.notification')
        <div class="uploader-files before-preview"> 
            <img relative-src="-log-upload.png" class="upload-file-icon" data-hook="upload-file-icon" src="-log-upload.png">

            <div class="upload-wrapper">
                <div class="fileUpload  btn btn-primary margin-none">
                    <span>Upload Image</span>
                    <input title="@DES_ImageBanner()" id="uploadFile"  required id="uploadBtn" multiple name="images[]" type="file" class="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-success">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        function imagesPreview(input, placeToInsertImagePreview)
        {   
            if (input.files) {
                var filesAmount = input.files.length;

                // console.log(filesAmount);
                var arrayCollection = [];
                $.each(input.files, function( index, value ) {
                    // console.log(value)
                    arrayCollection.push(value);
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                        console.log(index);
                        $(".current-preview").append("<div id='img-wrapper-"+index+"'> <img class='col-lg-3' src='"+event.target.result+"'> <button class='remove-"+index+"' type='button'> Remove </button> </div>");
                        $(".remove-"+index).click(function(){
                            $(this).parent('#img-wrapper-'+index).remove();
                        });
                    }
                        // console.log(input.files[i]);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(arrayCollection[index]);
                });
            }
        }

        $('#uploadFile').on('change', function() {
            imagesPreview(this, '.current-preview');
        });
    });
```

Laravel:dd() Method

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#273 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "961339_616747031754013_1312921563_n.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpAe4uNh"
    basename: "phpAe4uNh"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpAe4uNh"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpAe4uNh"
    aTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    mTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    cTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    inode: 1058393
    size: 119469
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 33
    group: 33
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  1 => UploadedFile {#283 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "10331570_616745628420820_1275369630_n.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php2uA2ka"
    basename: "php2uA2ka"
    pathname: "/tmp/php2uA2ka"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/php2uA2ka"
    aTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    mTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    cTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    inode: 1058394
    size: 141129
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 33
    group: 33
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  2 => UploadedFile {#284 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "10342661_616752931753423_1911417730_n.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpdQpDS2"
    basename: "phpdQpDS2"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpdQpDS2"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpdQpDS2"
    aTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    mTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    cTime: 2019-11-10 11:27:02
    inode: 1058395
    size: 137034
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 33
    group: 33
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

Please help, Thanks

Comment: you are removing images only from `.current-preview` div not from the `images[]` array

Comment: by default in this object :: **input.files** I have retrieved all images, We can't delete from existing and image upload in array.

Comment: you are using `id` twice in input tag, that might be creating problem

Answer (score 0):

you should remove this line

```
<input title="@DES_ImageBanner()" id="uploadFile"  required id="uploadBtn" multiple name="images[]" type="file" class="upload" />
```

for each removed image